# Как в VS Code настроить терминал в Linux(Fedora 37)?

Tags: linux, консоль, visual-studio-code, fedora

Проблема заключается в том, что встроенный в VS Code терминал не видит внешнюю среду linux(если так можно выразиться), а именно когда я пытаюсь прописать команду `npm -v` - ответом постоянно выводится:

```
bash-5.1$ npm -v
bash: npm: command not found
```

В то время как в обычном терминале при выполнении этой команды следующий результат:

```
bash-5.2$ npm -v
9.2.0
```

Я пробовал повторно устанавливать nodejs, а также переустанавливать VS Code.
В настройка терминала прописал следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перезагружал после этого и систему, и также на "всякий" снова переустанавливал vs code.
Изначально в поле "Extend terminal" было прописано "gnome-terminal", как вы понимаете - это не работало.

Каждый раз при открытии интегрированного терминала bash(в самом VS Code) - сразу же выпадает вот это(прикрепляю именно картинку для наглядности - не кидайтесь тапками):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как можно увидеть, terminal почему-то ищется в `/home`, однако в настройках редактора кода я прописал `/root/.bashrc`

К слову, чтобы не было сомнений в том, что npm и правда рабочий на устройсве - у меня спокойно получилось зайти в папку с проектом(**НЕ** со встроенного терминала в VS Code), скачанным с репозитория и затем выполнить команду `npm install` - все необходимые зависимости были установлены.

Что я должен сделать, чтобы можно было использовать менеджер npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Пока не спросишь - ответ не найдешь"(с)

Ответ до банального прост. Я устанавливал VS Code с помощью пакетного менеджера fedora(с графическим интерфейсом).

Помогло его удаление и установка версии "Code - OSS" с официального сайта visualstudio.